# Can't replace '\n' with '\\' for whatever reason

Tags: sed, backslash, tr

I have a whole bunch of files, and I wish to change something like this:

```
My line of text

My other line of text
```

Into

```
My line of text\\
My other line of text
```

Seems simple, but somehow it isn't. I have tried `sed s,"\n\n","\\\\\n",` as well as `tr '\n' '\\'` and about 20 other incarnations of these commands.

There must be something going on which I don't understand... but I'm completely lost as to why nothing is working. I've had some comical things happening too, like when cat'ing out the file, it doesn't print newlines, only writes over where the rest was written.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: `sed` operates on a line-by-line basis. You can't replace newlines with it (not without fancier tricks). `tr` on the other hand should work just fine (though will replace *all* newlines and only with a single `\`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed works on lines. It fetches a line, applies your code to it, fetches the next line, and so forth. Since lines are treated individually, multiline regexes don't work quite so easily.

In order to use multiline regexes with sed, you have to first assemble the file in the pattern space and then work on it:

```
sed ':a $!{ N; ba }; s/\n\n/\\\\\n/g' filename
```

The trick here is the

```
:a $!{ N; ba }
```

This works as follows:

```
:a     # jump label for looping
$!{    # if the end of the input has not been reached
  N    # fetch the next line and append it to what we already have
  ba   # go to :a
}
```

Once this is over, the whole file is in the pattern space, and multiline regexes can be applied to it. Of course, this requires that the file is small enough to fit into memory.

Comment: That did it. Thank you for explaining so clearly, what would otherwise have been mumbo jumbo to me.

Answer (score 0):

sed is line-oriented and so is inappropriate to try to use on problems that span lines. You just need to use a record-oriented tool like awk:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{gsub(/\n\n/,"\\\\\n")}1' file
My line of text\\
My other line of text
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` that solve this:

If the the blank lines could contains tabs or spaces, user this:

```
awk '!NF{a=a"//"} b{print a} {a=$0;b=NF} END {print a}' file
My line of text//
My other line of text
```

If blank line is just blank with nothing, this should do:

```
awk '!NF{a=a"//"} a!=""{print a} {a=$0} END {print a}' file
```

Comment: That would fail if `a` had numeric value zero.

Comment: @EdMorton Uff, I did fell into that again....  How test if  `a` is a blank line or line with spaces/tabs? This test will print a blank line  `a==0||a` at the top

Comment: `a!=""` I think is what you want.

Comment: @EdMorton That work only if line does not have spaces or tabs.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP wants lines that contain only spaces and tabs treated differently from lines that contain other chars.

Comment: @EdMorton I do not now either :)  But for the test of it, I added another version that should work.

Comment: I guess I'm swayed by the OPs `sed` attempt which searched for `\n\n` and so would treat lines containing only spaces the same as lines containing anything else. Of course it's always debatable how useful it is to guess at requirements based on a script that doesn't do what's required :-).

Comment: FWIW you could do `a~/[^[:blank:]]/` instead of introducing `b`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s|\n$|//|;P;D' file
```

This keeps 2 lines in the pattern space at any point in time and replaces an empty line by a double slash.